# Applicative Functors and Left from Either

Tags: haskell, functor, either, applicative

I have been working through the [great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com) book, but I am struggling slightly with Applicative Functors.

In the following example `max` is applied to the contents of the two Maybe functors and returns `Just 6`.

```
max <$> Just 3 <*> Just 6
```

Why in the following example is `Left "Hello"` returned instead of the contents of the Either functors: `Left "Hello World"`?

```
(++) <$> Left "Hello" <*> Left " World"
```

Comment: It's a traditional usage of Either that Right represents a value you're interested in, whereas Left represents a failure. Right (correct) values can be combined and modified using Applicative and Functor, whereas a Left over bad value will stubbornly persist, so it's good for things like reporting the first error the way a simple compiler might.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the type parameter in the `Functor` instance (and `Applicative` etc.) is the second type parameter. In

```
Either a b
```

the `a` type, and the `Left` values are not affected by functorial or applicative operations, because they are considered failure cases or otherwise inaccessible.

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Left x)  = Left x
    fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

Use `Right`,

```
(++)  <$> Right "Hello" <*> Right " World"
```

to get concatenation.

Comment: If you want to flip the type variables, you can use the `Data.EitherR` module from the `errors` package.  This provides two options: `flipE`, which flips an argument `Either` or `EitherR` which wraps it in a newtype that swaps the variable order, giving the symmetric `Functor` and `Applicative` instances.

Answer (score 11):

To add to Daniel's excellent answer, there are a couple points I'd like to make:

First, [here's](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Applicative.html#%3C%2A) the Applicative instance:

```
instance Applicative (Either e) where
    pure             =  Right
    Left  e  <*>  _  =  Left e
    Right f  <*>  r  =  fmap f r
```

You can see that this is 'short-circuiting' -- as soon as it hits a `Left`, it aborts and returns that Left.  You can check this with poor man's strictness analysis:

```
ghci> (++) <$> Left "Hello" <*> undefined 
Left "Hello"                              -- <<== it's not undefined :) !!

ghci>  (++) <$> Right "Hello" <*> undefined 
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined          -- <<== undefined ... :(

ghci> Left "oops" <*> undefined <*> undefined 
Left "oops"                               -- <<== :)

ghci> Right (++) <*> undefined <*> undefined 
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined          -- <<== :(
```

Second, your example is slightly tricky.  In general, the type of the function and the `e` in `Either e` are not related.  Here's `<*>`s type:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

If we make the substitution `f` -->> `Either e`, we get:

```
(<*>) :: Either e (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b
```

Although in your example, `e` and `a` match, in general they won't, which means you can't polymorphically implement an Applicative instance for `Either e` which applies the function to a left-hand argument.